# how to make 3G USB Modem work with ubuntu?

Tags: 11.10, usb-modem

I have one USB dongle for internet access initially i was using it with windows now i have installed Ubuntu 11.10. and the usb dongle is not working.It has inbuilt card reader too and that working fine.I dont know what to do.

help guys.

here is the screenshot for **lsusb** command[image]

Comment: Same question....Please help Guys.......

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you need to use usb-modeswitch, see this previous question [Help with implementing usb_modeswitch](https://askubuntu.com/q/43805/18190)

Answer (score 0):

## Try Voda's Betavine Connection Manager.

It supports a wide range of modem devices. Try to connect from that software.
https://forge.betavine.net/frs/?group_id=76&release_id=285