# Cell phone Texet doesn't mount as a storage device

Tags: usb, storage

Ubuntu 16.04. No mount point in the file manager. `dmesg:`

```
[  607.212885] usb 7-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0e8d, idProduct=0002
[  607.212889] usb 7-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=3, SerialNumber=4
[  607.212892] usb 7-2: Product: Product
[  607.212894] usb 7-2: Manufacturer: MediaTek Inc
[  607.212896] usb 7-2: SerialNumber: 534276607468940
[  607.218915] usb-storage 7-2:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[  607.219036] scsi host8: usb-storage 7-2:1.0
[  608.234915] scsi 8:0:0:0: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  608.237890] scsi 8:0:0:1: Direct-Access     MEDIATEK  FLASH DISK           PQ: 0 ANSI: 0 CCS
[  608.238252] sd 8:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[  608.238469] sd 8:0:0:1: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
[  608.250936] sd 8:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
[  608.253895] sd 8:0:0:1: [sde] 13312 512-byte logical blocks: (6.82 MB/6.50 MiB)
[  608.261896] sd 8:0:0:1: [sde] Write Protect is off
[  608.261899] sd 8:0:0:1: [sde] Mode Sense: 03 00 00 00
[  608.269914] sd 8:0:0:1: [sde] No Caching mode page found
[  608.269922] sd 8:0:0:1: [sde] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

UPD: storage mode is activated from phone's menu.  `find /dev/disk/by-id -name 'usb-*' \! -name '*-part?' -exec sudo lsblk -f {} +` returns nothing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Help with implementing usb\_modeswitch](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43805/help-with-implementing-usb-modeswitch)

Comment: Is has nothing with the switching of the mode. Cell phone is in storage mode by manual setting.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that relevant part of the equation and how you did it (Help us help you)

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `find /dev/disk/by-id -name 'usb-*' \! -name '*-part?' -exec sudo lsblk -f {} +`? Thanks.